# How to Best Show Infractions Per X Rolling Weeks

Tags: tables, timeline

I recently was given the opportunity to design an SSRS report tracking disciplinary actions.

Our organization decided an employee is allowed 3 infractions per rolling 12 weeks.

At the end of 6 months, management needs to know who was not compliant with policy.

I ended up offering them an Excel file with a different tab for each 12 week period in the last 6 months, each new week starting a "new" rolling 12 week period.

I'm immensely dissatisfied with this solution,  but struggle to think of an alternative.

This will be a hotly contested disciplinary action, so the employee needs to be able to see *exactly when* they were out of compliance, but management just needs a broad view of **who** and **when**

Because I've worked at several organizations with at least one "rolling X week" policy, I'm curious: is there a standard way to present this sort of data?

Comment: I haven't seen any standard way to present this type of data since it will not be something that is publicly visible, and therefore not real way to compare what different organisations do. Perhaps there are standard reporting metrics used in HR that you can investigate with subject matter experts.